# Imprimir en python

Tags: python, tkinter, imprimir

Buen día, me encuentro desarrollando un programa que imprima tickets (impresora termica) en python, pero no encuentro como tal una manera, no se si alguien la conozca.
Otra duda también es que si existe la manera de que una ventana de python pueda guardarse como imaginen o pdf

Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Mi mejor opcion para imprimir ha sido wxpython. Lamentablemente, no parece existir un modulo que se encargue unicamente de enviar a imprimir. Y la unica forma que conosco de guardar la ventana como imagen es con un screenshot.

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer seria recurrir un poco al desarrollo web y hacer una plantilla en html y pasarle los parametros que vos desea imprimir y convertir esa plantilla a PDF, es lo unico que se me ocurre que creo que es posible realizar

Answer (score 0):

Hola si te entendi bien buscas una libreria para imprimir tickets,

https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Caso USB

```
from escpos.printer import Usb

""" Seiko Epson Corp. Receipt Printer (EPSON TM-T88III) """
p = Usb(0x04b8, 0x0202, 0, profile="TM-T88III")
p.text("Hello World\n")
p.image("logo.gif")
p.barcode('1324354657687', 'EAN13', 64, 2, '', '')
p.cut()
```

Hay mas ejemplos de red, serial etc en el primer link

link instalacion: https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html

Espero que te sea de ayuda.